# Como evitar HTML injection e XSS em páginas .JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, xss

No `PHP` já vi usos de `htmlspecialchars` e `mysqli`. Mas no Java existe alguma forma de evitar XSS e HTML injection?

Também gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor maneira (a mais segura): Escapando os elementos (`HTML`, `Javascript`) ou inserindo uma tag `<pre>` para visualizar os dados para que isto não afete a página?

Comment: De cara, sem pensar muito já digo que a tag `<pre>` não resolve sem mais algum outro tipo de tratamento mais complexo junto, pois nesse caso o hacker começaria o HTML injetado com `</pre>` e o terminaria com `<pre>`.

Comment: Yeap. Eu vi uma implementação no WhatsApp Web em que usa-se a tag `<pre>` em conjunto com `<span>`

Comment: [Para ler enquanto não aparece uma resposta](http://blog.caelum.com.br/prevenindo-ataques-de-html-injection/).

Answer (score 1):

### JSP's

A maneira mais simples, é utilizar a tag [out](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) da [biblioteca JSTL Core](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html). Exemplo:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:out value="${suaVariavel}" />
```

seria o mesmo que:

```
<c:out value="${suaVariavel}" escapeXml="true" />
```

[Exemplo mais detalhado neste link de referência](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm)

### Um erro comum

**Achar que a JSTL já vem dentro dos containers WEB** e esquecer de colocar a JSTL no projeto, que pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar), ou, ser importada como dependência em um projeto maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

### Vale a pena dar uma olhada ...

[ESAPI - Segurança extra para aplicações WEB](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)

Uma lib utilitária que implementa diversos mecanismos de segurança. Permite ler de forma segura cookies, parâmetros da request, sessão e outros.

Answer (score 0):

Como o Victor disse, o `<pre>` não evita isto, talvez você esteja pensando que está tag converta o conteúdo para entidades, mas talvez seja apenas uma confusão.

Eu pessoalmente, permito a gravação exata do que foi "escrito", mas no momento da leitura que eu utilizo métodos semelhantes ao `htmlspecialchars`, assim evita conflitos, pois os textos não sofreram alterações na gravação.

Se a sua preocupação é ler os dados de um banco e imprimir na tela, você pode usar no momento de ler os dados da linha:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String data = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("<script>alert(1);</script>");
```

Não sei como está o seu código, e qual framework você usa, mas acredito que o sentido seja sempre este, "escapar" o conteudo na hora de exibir (corrija-me se eu estiver enganado).

**Documentação:** [StringEscapeUtils (Commons Lang 2.6 API)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String))

Comment: Só a ter cuidado com gente que crafta coisas como `<s
cript>` (eu nao sei se o editor deixa, mas existe um line-break entre `<s` e `cript>`) e o browser consegue perceber que isso === `<script>`. Em Javascript existe uma library espetacular chamada [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) talvez exista algo para Java, também?

Comment: @MoshMage se queres mostrar como HTML mesmo o DOMPurify parece bom, mas se não quer mostrar então converter o HTML em entidades acho que já basta.

Comment: Como XSS normalmente é para correr na maquina dos clientes, injecta-se em sítios que se pode usar html; Imagina um WYSIWYG que fica desprotegido? Ele quererá mostrar como HTML *e* não lhe apetece nada ter ali uns scripts escondidos ;P

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu o que eu disse @MoshMage, vou tentar fazer mais claro para você o texto, **SE não** houver necessidade de mostrar o HTML gerado pelo usuário o `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` é suficiente, **SE há** a necessidade de mostrar o HTML criado pelo usuário então ferramentas semelhantes ao DOMPurify são boas soluções. Entendeu? Eu não te critiquei, só coloquei o momento da necessidade.

Comment: Na boa :) Mas eu referi mesmo o dompurify porque realmente li mal a pergunta, percebi que ele queria mostrar o html. my bad ^^